# python tkinter | after jump to parent class function how to back to subclass function?

Tags: python, tkinter

There is the code.

```
class Popup(Menu):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Menu.__init__(self, parent,tearoff=0)
        self.add_command(label='click',command=self.right_click)

    def popup(self,x,y):
        try:
            self.tk_popup(x,y)
        finally:
            self.grab_release()
    
    def right_click(self):
        print('Click!')


class main(Popup):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        main_window=tkinter.Tk()
        self.label=tkinter.Label(main_window,text='test')
        self.label.pack()
        Popup.__init__(self,main_window)
        self.label.bind('<ButtonRelease-3>',lambda event: self.popup(event.x_root,event.y_root))
        main_window.mainloop()
    
    def click(self):
        self.label.config(text='click')


main()
```

I want to do main.click after Popup.right_click, but I have no idea how to back to subclass function?

Comment: Just call `self.click()` inside `right_click()`.

Comment: So a parent class can call a subclass function directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `self.click()` inside `right_click()`.  Suggest to define `click()` inside `Popup` as well in case `click()` is not defined inside subclass.  `click()` in subclass will override `click()` in `Popup` class.

```py
class Popup(Menu):
    ...

    def right_click(self):
        print('Click!')
        self.click()

    def click(self):
        pass
```

Comment: get it , much thanks!